# NSMutableArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: requires intermediate results array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

`sortedarrayusingdescriptors` doesn't appear to do an in-place sort as I'd hoped.
It looks like it requires an additional array with which to sort into, and then you would clear your original mutable array and repopulate it with the results of the sorted array.

For example, I expected this to work...

```
@interface SomeClass
{
   NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOfItems;
}

-(void)sortItems
    {
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"age" ascending:NO];

        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor1,descriptor2, nil];
        mutableArrayOfItems = [mutableArrayOfItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
    }
```

But instead had to do this....

```
@interface SomeClass
{
   NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOfItems;
}

-(void)sortItems
    {
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"age" ascending:NO];

        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor1,descriptor2, nil];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [mutableArrayOfItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
        [mutableArrayOfItems removeAllObjects];
        [mutableArrayOfItems addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `sortedArray...` returns its result. Use `sortUsingDescriptors:` to sort in-place. The method names are intended to be self-descriptive. "Sort" is an imperative verb: it _does something to_ the receiver. "Sorted array" is a noun: it _provides another object_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Funny how things become forehead slapping obvious AFTER they are pointed out... lol.

Comment: Note that **mutating** and **in-place** are two very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use a method that creates a new array. What about calling sortUsingDescriptors: instead?